# PHP For-Loop Syntax Error

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am getting a syntax error:

> unexpected ']'

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$output = "";
for ($i=1; $i<16; $i++) {
    $output .= $_POST["DepositCode" . i . ] . "," . $_POST["textfield" . i . ] . "," . $_POST["AccountNum" . i . ] . " \r\n"; 
    }

$file ='textt.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $output);
?>
```

Comment: Should be `$_POST["DepositCode" . i]` - remove the last dot (`.`)

Comment: also should be $i not i.   thanks everyone

Answer (score 6):

```
$output .= $_POST["DepositCode" . i . ] . "," etc...
                                    ^--- extra concat operator
```

as well as two other places later in the same line. `i` by itself is invalid as well. it should be `$i`. The whole line could be replaced with:

```
$output .= $_POST["DepositCode$i"] . "," . $_POST["textfield$i"] . "," . $_POST["AccountNum$i"] . " \r\n";
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
$output .= $_POST["DepositCode" . i . ] . "," . $_POST["textfield" . i . ] . "," . $_POST["AccountNum" . i . ] . " \r\n";
```

The right code is:

```
$output .= $_POST["DepositCode" . $i] . "," . $_POST["textfield" . $i] . "," . $_POST["AccountNum" . $i] . " \r\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$_POST["X" . i . ] >> $_POST["X" . i]
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your 'i'-s in the for-loop. They are all missing the '$'-sign.

Edit: 
And check the other posts concerning the concatination.

Comment: And en extra dot before the `]`